# Restricting Android Broadcast Receiver from specific app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I have 2 applications.
If I use service, I can set permission so only `app1` can send intent to `app2`:
Define permission in `app2` (`protection level: signature`), and 
use that permission in `app1`.
Service in `app2` is protected by that permission.
In this way, only `app1` can send an intent to a service on `app2`,
and no other app (unless my signature is leaked) can send intent to
service on `app2`.

Can I do the same with Broadcast Receiver?

- app1: sendBroadcast(intent, permission)
- app2: define permission, use that permission.

To my understanding for using sendBroadcast(intent, permission), the
application doesn't need to "use" the permission. Meaning ANY application
can send intent to `app2`. Those permission parameters only checked against
`app2`, to avoid other applications  to receive this intent.
(If I remove `app2`, and install fake `app2` with the same permission string
 defined, fake `app2` can get intent from `app1`, which is unexpected)

BTW, If application define the permission and use it itself, the 
 protectionLevel(signature) seems to have no meaning. Is this true?

Now, I can set additional permission:

- app1: Define permission, use that permission.
- app2: Receiver restricted only for that permission.

Again, if one removes `app1`, installs fake `app1` with the very same
permission, then fake `app1` can send fake intent to `app2`.
What can I do to prevent `app2` from receiving fake intent?

Thanks

Comment: The <receiver> tag can also define what permission the broadcasters should have, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#prmsn

Answer (score 6):

The  tag can also define what permission the broadcasters should have, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#prmsn

I means you can protected your receiver from unauthorized broadcasts by coding like this:

```
...
<permission android:name="com.yourapp.PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:label="@string/permission_label"
        android:description="@string/permission_desc">
</permission>
...

<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:permission="com.yourapp.PERMISSION">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.yourapp.ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

**Sender App**

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.karthik.apptx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Process;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void OnClickButton(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.karthik.apprx");
        intent.putExtra("PACKAGE_NAME", this.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("PID", Process.myPid());
        intent.putExtra("DATA", "Hello Karthik");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.karthik.apprx", "com.karthik.apprx.AppRxReceiver"));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karthik.apptx">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.karthik.PERMISSION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTx">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Receiver App (Written in Kotlin)**

*MyBroadcastReceiver.kt*

```
package com.karthik.apprx

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast

class AppRxReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(ctx: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("AppRxReceiver", intent.toString())
        Log.d("AppRxReceiver", intent?.getStringExtra("PACKAGE_NAME").toString())
        Log.d("AppRxReceiver", "" + intent?.getIntExtra("PID", 0))
        Log.d("AppRxReceiver", intent?.getStringExtra("DATA").toString())
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Received Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karthik.apprx">

    <permission
        android:name="com.karthik.PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppRx">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppRx.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".AppRxReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.karthik.PERMISSION">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.karthik.apptx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

PS: For my convenience, I have chosen to write Sender-App in Java and Receiver-App in Kotlin.