# Restricting bradcast receiver for my application only

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a broadcast receiver for my application. Now i want to restrict that receiver to my application only. What i need to do for that.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528608/restricting-android-broadcast-receiver-from-specific-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using : `android:exported="false"` for your broadcast receiver in the manifest file

Answer (score 1):

You can `unregister` your `BroadCastReciever` when your Home Activity is destroyed.