# Android: are context-registered broadcast receivers exported?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

If I register a broadcast receiver say in my activity like this,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { ... };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.MY_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}
```

Is this receiver exported? if another app broadcasts `com.example.MY_ACTION`, will it be received by `myReceiver`?

If it is, I assume I need to use the form of `registerReceiver()` that accepts a string permission, and then define that permission in my manifest, giving it a high protection level (such as signature). Is that correct? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: They are exported.  For ways to protect, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528608/restricting-android-broadcast-receiver-from-specific-app

Comment: that post is about manifest-registered receivers. i'm specifically asking about programmatically registered receivers.

Comment: Makes no difference. Once your app is running and you start the receiver anyone can send intents to you.

Comment: well, you need to cite your source, because this quote from the android docs contradicts you: "Register a BroadcastReceiver to be run in the main activity thread. The receiver will be called with any broadcast Intent that matches filter, *in the main application thread.*".

Comment: For myself I do not need to cite the source, just my experience of how it works. *shrug* good luck on your project.

Comment: ignore the docs, make up your own rules, and hope you are smarter than the people who wrote them. sounds like a recipe for success.

Comment: Ok, one last time just for you this time from the docs, right at the top of the BroadcastReceiver API: If you don't need to send broadcasts across applications, consider using this class with LocalBroadcastManager instead of the more general facilities described below. This will give you a much more efficient implementation (no cross-process communication needed) and allow you to avoid thinking about any security issues related to other applications being able to receive or send your broadcasts.  Anymore questions?

Comment: that's a possible solution to a problem, but i don't think it answers the question.

Comment: p.s., if you write up the LocalBroadcastManager idea as an answer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Can't we get an answer to this question please?! Someone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the api docs on the BroadcastReceiver API:

> If you don't need to send broadcasts across applications, consider
>   using this class with [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) instead of the more
>   general facilities described below. This will give you a much more
>   efficient implementation (no cross-process communication needed) and
>   allow you to avoid thinking about any security issues related to other
>   applications being able to receive or send your broadcasts.

That way at least you can keep the receiver only inside your application.

Comment: while this does not technically answer my question, it is a solution to the implied problem.

Comment: Not viable solution if you have to send broadcasts inside application but across process boundaries.

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen ok, but that was not what the question was about, now was it?

Comment: @Kaediil No, it was not. However, it might be useful information to someone - at least for me it was not too clear in the beginning that local broadcasts do not work across process boundaries inside one application. It might be useful to include this information in your answer also.

Comment: In my case I need to send broadcasts that are to be received both by static receivers (protected by exported="false") AND dynamic receivers. The only solutions I have found is then to use a permission both defined in and used by the application (unless you want to send a normal broadcast AND a local broadcast with a different action, which would be very messy).

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` comes from AppCompat. Any ways of doing this without it, only using Android SDK?

Answer (score 5):

To spare others the work and for my own archiving purposes: Yes, context-registered receivers **are** exported by default.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#BroadcastReceivers) but you can validate this quickly by running a separate app sending a custom broadcast. I tested this on APIs 16-29, the broadcast will be received and so every package will be able to send to your receiver (which can be a security flaw).

---

To solve the issue without using local broadcasts ([should be used wherever possible](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#security-and-best-practices)) you are on the right track in defining a custom permission and [restricting broadcasts to apps that have requested that permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#restrict-broadcasts-permissions).
For the sake of completeness:

Define and use a custom permission in the manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.bcrtest.BROADCAST_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.bcrtest.BROADCAST_PERMISSION" />
```

Register receiver with permission:

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_INTENT_ACTION), "com.example.bcrtest.BROADCAST_PERMISSION", null );
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, use a `LocalBroadcastManager` like this:

```
lateinit var localBroadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager

localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)

localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(
            myReceiver,
            filter
        )
```