# How do I receive download complete broadcasts issued only by my app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I used the following method, but how to set the broadcastPermission to only receive broadcast from the app itself?

```
context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE), null, compressHandler);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Only the DownloadManager should be sending ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, why would your app send it?

Comment: Sorry for me bad English, I am saying if some other app is downloading stuff using the DownloadManager, will it mess up with my broadcast receiver when the download is completed? How could i set permission to restrict that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems you are trying to solve:

1. You only want to receive intents that were broadcast by the DownloadManager
2. You only want to receive intents that were are the result of a download you started

To solve the 1st problem you should use this String "android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS" as your broadcastPermission in this method: [Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter, java.lang.String, android.os.Handler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler%29)

One way to solve the 2nd problem is to store the long ID returned by the method `DownloadManager.html#enqueue(android.app.DownloadManager.Request)`. Then when you receive an intent you check to see if the ID is a match to one you requested. If so then you know it was your request. The Intent contains the ID in an extra `DownloadManager.html#EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager`, e.g.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onComplete,
  new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

In this case you are just using `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` as a constant value but will not receive anyting from android `DownloadManager` class

If you want to set permission to your broadcast [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528608/restricting-android-broadcast-receiver-from-specific-app)

Comment: thanks, but I need to use the function I posted because I want to pass the onComplete to a scheduler, so it is handled in a different thread. so instead of passing "null" as the broadcastPermission, what could I do?