# Getting downloads information requested by application

Tags: android

I'm using an ad network in my application to monetize it. I show a banner from this ad network and when the user clicks it it will be redirected to google play to let him download a game/utility. I need to know if user started the download process and if it finished. I have seen I can query the download manager to check for downloads being downloaded, etc... but what I really need to know are the downloads requested by my application (That were requested by the ad network sdk in the end). Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this thread. [How do I receive download complete broadcasts issued only by my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943414/how-do-i-receive-download-complete-broadcasts-issued-only-by-my-app)
However in your case, the playstore will issue the download app request to the download manager. So I dont think its possible to track the exact downloads made by your app. You can track the click from any adnetwork sdk using the callback listeners and then check if a download occurred using the download manager. But again you cant be sure that some other app didn't download the same app at almost same time.